# How to optimize network throughput with AWS Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, odbc

I've read about the `sslcompression` ODBC option in PostgreSQL, which seems to have some artifacts left in Redshift. But, I'm unsure if it is supported at all, and documentation seems to show that `sslcompression` has been deprecated for security concerns.

With that said, I have large queries that appear (in cloudwatch) to be transferring about 600MB/s between the Redshift cluster and an EC2 instance over a private VPC Endpoint.

This seems pretty fast, but it's not fast enough.

Are there any Redshift ODBC options which enable compression of the network data (perhaps something shared with PostgresSQL)? Are there any settings or other options (AWS Services?) to consider to drastically increase this throughput?

The Redshift cluster is a 4x Node ra3.xlplus.
The EC2 instance is a z1d.2xlarge.